# Oracle trigger checks previous record before insert/update

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger that prevents a student from enrolling into a new module if he has any outstanding bills.

```
studID    studNRIC     paymentStatus
-------------------------------------
200       F7654672F      Non Payment
```

it would reject the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO student(studID, studNRIC, paymentStatus) 
  VALUES (201, 'F7654672F', 'Good');
```

I've came out with the following trigger but I'm still able to insert a new student.

```
set define off;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reject_new_account
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Student
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    totover NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*)
INTO   totover
FROM   Student
WHERE :NEW.nric = student.nric
  AND :NEW.paymentStatus = 'Non Payment';

IF totover > 0 THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20002, 
    'Student' || :NEW.nric ||
    ' has outstanding bills' );
END IF;
END;
/
```

there's seems to be a problem with line 13 `AND :NEW.paymentStatus = 'Non Payment';`
so how do I go about doing this?

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
studID              INTEGER NOT NULL,
firstName           CHAR(25) NULL,
lastName            CHAR(25) NULL,
NRIC                CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
paymentStatus       CHAR(25) Default 'Good',
CONSTRAINT stud_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (studID),
CONSTRAINT studPaymentStatus_type CHECK (PaymentStatus IN ('Late Payment', 'Non Payment', 'Good'))
);
```

Comment: So studID 200 and studID 201 can refer to the same student?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this trigger.

First if you want to prevent an INSERT you need to use a BEFORE trigger. An AFTER trigger will fire after the insert has successfully completed, by which point it is too late to stop the insert.

Secondly, I'm unsure about what you are trying to achieve with your SQL statement. Since the trigger is attached to the customer table you don't need to do a select on the customer table to access the record data. You can just do:

```
IF :NEW.badstatus = 'Non Payment'
THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20002, 
    'Employee ' || :NEW.nric ||
    ' already has 5 readings' );
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to check if the new record has a bad status, you want to check if the existing customer records have a bad status. As James mentioned, a `BEFORE` trigger probably makes more sense, but that depends on what you are trying to do, whether the insert gets rollback or not by the caller, etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reject_new_account
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Customer
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    totover NUMBER(3);

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT (*)
      INTO totover
      FROM Customer c
      WHERE c.nric = :NEW.nric
        AND c.badstatus = 'Non Payment';

    IF totover > 0 THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20002, 
         'Employee ' || :NEW.nric ||
         ' already has 5 readings' );
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: @James Xabregasthanks for the 2 suggestions. And yes, stud 200 and 201 are the same student. So if the student has not paid his fee he is not allowed to enroll to a new course. is this possible to be done through a trigger. or is it possible with :OLD?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you have discovered, you cannot select from the same table that a row-level trigger is defined against; it causes a table mutating exception. You have attempted to get round this by adding the autonomous transaction pragma. Unfortunately, although this works, it is just covering up your mistake in methodology.

In order to properly create this validation using a trigger a procedure should be created to obtain user-specified locks so the validation can be correctly serialized in a multi-user environment.

```
PROCEDURE request_lock
  (p_lockname                     IN     VARCHAR2
  ,p_lockmode                     IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT dbms_lock.x_mode
  ,p_timeout                      IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 60
  ,p_release_on_commit            IN     BOOLEAN  DEFAULT TRUE
  ,p_expiration_secs              IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 600)
IS
  -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique issues implicit commit, so place in its own
  -- transaction so it does not affect the caller
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_lockhandle                   VARCHAR2(128);
  l_return                       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique
    (lockname                       => p_lockname
    ,lockhandle                     => p_lockhandle
    ,expiration_secs                => p_expiration_secs);
  l_return := dbms_lock.request
    (lockhandle                     => l_lockhandle
    ,lockmode                       => p_lockmode
    ,timeout                        => p_timeout
    ,release_on_commit              => p_release_on_commit);
  IF    (l_return = 1) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Timeout');
  ELSIF (l_return = 2) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Deadlock');
  ELSIF (l_return = 3) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Parameter Error');
  ELSIF (l_return = 5) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Illegal Lock Handle');
  ELSIF (l_return not in (0,4)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Unknown Return Value ' || l_return);
  END IF;
  -- Must COMMIT an autonomous transaction
  COMMIT;
END request_lock;
```

This procedure can then be used in a compound trigger (assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reject_new_account
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON student
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of inserted/updated students
  g_studIDs sys.odcinumberlist;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
-- Reset the internal student table
  g_studIDs := g_studIDs();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the inserted/updated students; the payment status may be updated
  -- without checking the constraint
  IF (  INSERTING
     OR (   UPDATING
        AND (  :new.studID <> :old.studID
            OR :new.NRIC <> :old.NRIC)))
  THEN           
    g_studIDs.EXTEND;
    g_studIDs(g_studIDs.LAST) := :new.studID;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_students
  IS
    SELECT sdt.studID
         , sdt.NRIC
    FROM TABLE(g_studIDs) sid
         INNER JOIN student sdt
          ON (sdt.studID = sid.column_value)
    ORDER BY sdt.NRIC;
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_studID student.studID%TYPE
    ,p_NRIC   student.studNRIC%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM student sdt
    WHERE sdt.NRIC = p_NRIC
    AND sdt.paymentStatus = 'Bad Payment'
    AND sdt.studID <> p_studID;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any inserted/updated student there exists another record for
  -- the same NRIC with a Bad Payment status. Serialise the constraint for each
  -- NRIC so concurrent transactions do not affect each other
  FOR r_student IN csr_students LOOP
    request_lock('REJECT_NEW_ACCOUNT_' || r_student.NRIC);
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_student.studID, r_student.NRIC);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Student ' || r_student.NRIC || ' has Bad Payment status');
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```

Comment: is it still possible to do if I'm not looking at a multi user environment? There will only be one user who will be manipulating with the data so I don't really need the locking mechanism. my 'badStatus' is in my student table. so is there any other way to work this around?

Comment: Probably, you would need to be more precise in the definition of your tables and the definition of the constraint you wish to apply. For instance, you have not included in your question the definition of a table with a badStatus column.

Comment: I've edited the question and listed my table structure as well as the constraint which I have done. could you help me take a look? much appreciated.

Comment: You have not included the customer table, on which your original trigger was based. Your student table does not include a badStatus column, is this correct?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion. there's only one table named student and my trigger will be targeting the student as well. I've already tidy up the question. Sorry for mixing up the attributes.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the student table definition. If you do not wish to serialize the constraint you can remove the call the request_lock procedure. However, this does mean that it is not guaranteed that you constraint will be enforced in a multi-user environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` for you and replace it with an exception to handle the issue, can you try if it works.

```
set define off;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reject_new_account
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    totover CHAR(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct badStatus
    INTO totover
    FROM customer
    WHERE :NEW.nric = CUSTOMER.nric;
    IF totover = 'Non Payment' THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20003, 
        'Customer ' || :NEW.firstName||''||:NEW.lastName ||
        ' cannot create new account due to bad payment' );
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQLERRM(-20299)));
END;
/
```

Comment: @user2900611 As I explained in my answer, this will not work generically as you cannot select from the the same table as a row-level trigger is based on. To check instead of using INSERT...VALUES... use INSERT..SELECT...FROM dual and this will raise a ORA-04091 table is mutating exception.